# Find angle between two objects while taking another object as center in Unity using C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to find angle between two stationary objects while taking a moving object as center. I have tried a lot like finding distance between all the objects and then applying [cosine rule](http://www.teacherschoice.com.au/maths_library/trigonometry/solve_trig_sss.htm) to find angle but it calculates the wrong angle. This is the code. First it calculates the desired angles position(greatest, smallest or medium), then calling calculate angle.

[image]

```
void GenerateAngle()
{
if (transform.position != currentPos)
    {
        float angle = 0;
        distancePillarRToPillarL = Vector3.Distance(PillarR.position, PillarL.position);
        distancePlayerToPillarL = Vector3.Distance(PillarL.position, transform.position);
        distancePlayerToPillarR = Vector3.Distance(PillarR.position, transform.position);
        print(distancePillarRToPillarL + "  " + distancePlayerToPillarL + "  " + distancePlayerToPillarR);

        if (distancePlayerToPillarR > distancePlayerToPillarL && distancePlayerToPillarR > distancePillarRToPillarL)
        {
            if (distancePillarRToPillarL > distancePlayerToPillarL)
            {
                angle = CalculateAngle(distancePlayerToPillarR, distancePillarRToPillarL, distancePlayerToPillarL, AnglePos.Medium);
            }
            else if (distancePlayerToPillarL > distancePillarRToPillarL)
            {
                angle = CalculateAngle(distancePlayerToPillarR, distancePlayerToPillarL, distancePillarRToPillarL, AnglePos.Smallest);
            }
        }
        else if (distancePlayerToPillarL > distancePlayerToPillarR && distancePlayerToPillarL > distancePillarRToPillarL)
        {
            if (distancePillarRToPillarL > distancePlayerToPillarR)
            {
                angle = CalculateAngle(distancePlayerToPillarL, distancePillarRToPillarL, distancePlayerToPillarR, AnglePos.Medium);
            }
            else if (distancePlayerToPillarR > distancePillarRToPillarL)
            {
                angle = CalculateAngle(distancePlayerToPillarL, distancePillarRToPillarL, distancePlayerToPillarR, AnglePos.Smallest);
            }
        }
        else if (distancePillarRToPillarL > distancePlayerToPillarL && distancePillarRToPillarL > distancePlayerToPillarR)
        {
            if (distancePlayerToPillarL > distancePlayerToPillarR)
            {
                angle = CalculateAngle(distancePillarRToPillarL, distancePlayerToPillarL, distancePlayerToPillarR, AnglePos.Largest);
            }
            else if (distancePlayerToPillarR > distancePlayerToPillarL)
            {
                angle = CalculateAngle(distancePillarRToPillarL, distancePlayerToPillarR, distancePlayerToPillarL, AnglePos.Largest);
            }
        }
        print(angle);
        currentPos = transform.position;
    }


}



float CalculateAngle(float largest, float medium, float smallest, AnglePos pos)


 {
        float largestAngle = (Mathf.Acos((Mathf.Pow(medium, 2) + Mathf.Pow(smallest, 2) - Mathf.Pow(largest, 2)) / (2 * medium * smallest))) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        float angle;
        switch (pos)
        {
            case AnglePos.Medium:
                {
                    angle = Mathf.Asin((medium * Mathf.Sin(largestAngle)) / largest) * Mathf.Rad2Deg ;
                    return angle;
                }

        case AnglePos.Smallest:
            {
                angle = Mathf.Asin((smallest *  Mathf.Sin(largestAngle)) / largest) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
                return angle;
            }

        default:
            {
                return largestAngle;
            }

    }
```

}

Comment: "but it gives wrong results" try adding relevant code and example data with what you're expecting and why it's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want something like this?

```
Vector3 center = /*...*/
Vector3 a = /*...*/
Vector3 b = /*...*/

Vector3 directionA = Vector3.Normalize(center - a);
Vector3 directionB = Vector3.Normalize(center - b);

float angle = Vector3.Angle(directionA, directionB); //degrees
```

This calculates the angle between 2 object directions relative to a center.